# Why does the build_heap function in the heap sort algorithm not execute

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

The following python code for implementing heap sort algorithm and the max_heapify and build_heap functions are resulting in the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heap.py", line 30, in <module>
    build_heap(arr)
  File "heap.py", line 25, in build_heap
    for i in range(((int(len(array))-1)/2),0,-1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

And the code:

```
def left(i):
    return(2*i)
def right(i):
    return(2*i+1)
def max_heapify(array,i,heap_size):
    l=left(i)
    r=right(i)
    largest=i
    if(l<=heap_size and array[l]>array[i]):
        largest=l
    elif(r<=heap_size and array[r]>array[i]):
        largest=r
    if(largest!=i):
        swap(array,i,largest)
        max_heapify(array,largest)




def swap(array,a,b):
    array[a],array[b]=array[b],array[a]

def build_heap(array):
    heap_size=len(array)-1
    for i in range(((int(len(array))-1)/2),0,-1):
        max_heapify(array,i,heap_size)


arr=[0,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
build_heap(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Likely this is writtne in Python-2.x when this was integer division.

Answer (score 1):

`int(len(array) - 1) / 2` is a float, becuase you divide by 2 **after** converting to an integer. Just do `(len(array) - 1) // 2`, which will give an integer.

You should also call `max_heapify` for the first element of the list - so with both of these changes in mind, your loop needs to be `for i in range((len(array)-1)//2, -1, -1)`.

(I'm assuming this is just a typo but you're only passing two arguments to `max_heapify` when you call it from inside itself, you need to add `heap_size`).

Comment: arr=[0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
build_heap(arr)
print(arr)         this piece of code gives this output    [0, 7, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 6, 0, 8, 4, 10]
why is the algorithm not giving a max ordered heap ?

Answer (score 0):

This was likely written in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x). If you divide two integers in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), then you perform integer division. In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you can use `//` (which works for [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) as well):

```
def build_heap(array):
    heap_size=len(array)-1
    for i in range(heap_size//2, -1, -1):
        max_heapify(array,i,heap_size)
```